# Move sprite in straight line

Tags: c#, xna

I must apologies as this seems such a simple question but I have been trying to get it work for ages.

I have a sprite and two Vector2 variables and I want a sprite to move from one vector2 to another.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

this code works for me but it does a small move every click

```
//CurPos is the sprite current Position and DestPos is the Destination Position
Vector2 StepAnm = (CurPos - DestPos) / 60;
```

and in the update function

```
if (currentMouseState.LeftButton ==Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed&&lastMouseState.LeftButton ==Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released)
{
    if ((int)CurPos.X != (int)DestPos.X) 
    { 
        CurPos.X -= StepAnm.X; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question is possibly a duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7757 ?

Comment: I don't know but it doesn't work with me !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `Update` method.

The following will need to be set outside this code

```
Vector2 destPos;
Vector2 stepAnm; //Needs to be set when destPos is updated
float duration; //Could be dependent on distance or not

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float elapsedSeconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;


    float moveAmount = elapsedSeconds / duration;
    Vector2 movement = stepAnm * moveAmount;

    //This should fix going too far
    if (movement.LengthSquared() > destPos.DistanceSquared(curPos))
    {
        curPos = destPos;
    }
    else
    {
        curPos += stepAnm * moveAmount; //+= or -= depending on how you calculate stepAnm
    }
}
```

You will probably want to change it a little if you are using a constant speed system. I included the more general duration based system.

Comment: It is my first use of XNA so I need you to explain :)

Comment: No overload for method 'DistanceSquared' takes 0 arguments!